# Non-exhaustive patterns in function scalarNew

Tags: haskell

What does *"Non-exhaustive patterns in function scalarNew"* mean in this context?

```hs
scalarNew :: [Integer]->[Integer]->Integer
scalarNew (x:xs) (y:ys) 
     | (length xs == length ys) = x * y + scalarNew xs ys
     | otherwise = error "error"
```

Comment: Try to write a version without recursion. Hint: use `zipWith` and `sum`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to add the base case when using recursion. In this situation, the base case is when both are empty lists.

```
scalarNew :: [Integer] -> [Integer] -> Integer
scalarNew []     []        = 0
scalarNew []     (y:ys)    = error "error"
scalarNew (x:xs)    []     = error "error"
scalarNew (x:xs) (y:ys) 
  | length xs == length ys = x * y + scalarNew xs ys
  | otherwise = error "error"
```

edit: handle only-one-empty-list case

Comment: ok, i understand , thank u

Comment: don't forget to mark as solved ;)

Comment: You've neglected two cases: when only one of the two lists are empty. This will continue to produce an error in some cases.

Comment: @AJFarmar yep! forgot it actually. Already edited, thanks ;)